# Terminology question - authentication through encryption

Tags: encryption, authentication, access-control, hmac

I came across a number of somewhat similar solutions, which are based on the knowledge factor related to a symmetric key in particular:

- If a party was able to generate correct message authentication code, be it in form of HMAC...
- If a party was able to encrypt a piece of plaintext which decrypts to a message of expected structure...

... it means they are in posession of a symmetric key K, which in turn implies that this must be the party XYZ, unless the key has been compromised.

What is the common name for such authentication schemes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic term is ***proof of possession***.

It's most commonly used for a private key, where a prover needs to convince a verifier that the prover knows a certain private key. The most natural way to do this is for the verifier to send a challenge to the prover, and the prover signs this challenge with the private key. The verifier uses the public key to verify the signature. Only a party who knows the private key can produce a valid signature. The challenge should be unique, because otherwise an adversary who intercepted a response could replay the signed message without knowing the private key. It's also possible to generate a proof of possession by having the verifier send a challenge encrypted with the public key and the prover decrypt it and send it back.

From [RFC 2797 — Certificate Management Messages over CMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2797#section-2.1):

> "POP" is an acronym for "Proof of Possession".  POP refers to a value that can be used to prove that the private key corresponding to a public key is in the possession and can be used by an end-entity.

More generally, the term can be used with symmetric keys as well. For example [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7800) defines a proof of possession protocol for both [asymmetric](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7800#section-3.2) and [symmetric](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7800#section-3.3) keys.

Comment: I have found a definition which I like most: "Proof-of-possession is a means of proving that a party sending a message is in possession of a particular cryptographic key. This is used as a proof that the correct party is sending the message, under the assumption that only that sender has possession the key." Source: [The Increasing Importance of Proof-of-Possession to the Web](http://self-issued.info/papers/The_Increasing_Importance_of_Proof-of-Possession_to_the_Web.pdf) by Michael B. Jones

Answer (score -1):

This is known as a **Zero-Knowledge Proof**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof):

> In cryptography, a zero-knowledge proof or zero-knowledge protocol is
> a method by which one party (the prover) can prove to another party
> (the verifier) that they know a value x, without conveying any
> information apart from the fact that they know the value x.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at ZKP. However, what is interesting to me, is that despite ZKP-based authentication being used in some shape or form quite often, the community refrains from giving it a common name.

Comment: No, the examples in the question are not zero-knowledge. Zero-knowledge doesn't just mean that the whole value of x isn't disclosed, it's a much stronger condition.